# R CMD CHECK warnings with Rcpp packages on Windows

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I get such warnings when I run R CMD CHECK on my package, which uses **Rcpp**, **RccpCGAL**, **BH** and **RcppEigen** (below is a copy of one of these warnings triggered on R-hub):

```
C:/Users/USEReBkhIMHdJz/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/BH/include/boost/container/detail/copy_move_algo.hpp:184:19: warning: 'void* memmove(void*, const void*, size_t)' writing to an object of type 'value_type' {aka 'struct std::pair, std::allocator >, long long unsigned int> > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, long long unsigned int> > > > >, CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator, std::allocator >, long long unsigned int> > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, long long unsigned int> > > > > >'} with no trivial copy-assignment; use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
```

There's no warning on Linux, only on Windows (10).

Comment: It's a warning from `BH` so why do you label it `Rcpp`?   Besides the warning is a known old tale that the size of a `long` can vary.  I suspect the warnng only comes from the _i386_ part of the bi-arch build, and i386 will be gone by April when R 4.2.0 drops it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel On my Windows machine, I put the option `--no-multiarch` to R CMD CHECK, and I got these warnings; With i386 I get other warnings.

Comment: Ok, noted. Then it may be a something Boost does only on Windows, and that may or not be compiler dependent.  Have you ever looked closely enough at those headers? There are a million `#define` statement _conditioning_ on the environment.  In any event, this appears to be from CGAL so maybe talk to someone from that project.  As I said in the first comment, _this has nothing to do with Rcpp_.

Comment: Also, for completeness: your question is not reproducible, it does not show code, and it does not show how you invoke the code.  How do you think we can help you?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sorry, my code is [here](https://github.com/stla/RCGAL) but I don't know which part of it triggers these warnings. Maybe I should compile the functions once at time. I already talked to the author of RcppCGAL and I opened an issue on the CGAL repo.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I found a solution but it works only with R-4.2.0. It consists in not using boost and not including **BH** in **LinkingTo**. If I don't include **BH** with R-4.1.2, the installation fails, even if I don't use boost.