# R package define "LinkingTo" depending on OS

Tags: c++, r, boost, r-package, cran

I'm doing a R package which is linked to the **RcppCGAL** package, which contains the C++ library **CGAL**, which depends on the C++ library **Boost**. If I link my package to the **BH** package (in order to include **Boost**), then R CMD CHECK throws a warning on Windows (*"found significant warnings..."*) and then my package is not acceptable to CRAN. But with R-4.2.0, I don't need to link to **BH**, because Rtools42 contains the **Boost** library. Then I have my solution for Windows (I will just be obliged to force the **R >= 4.2.0** dependency). But if I don't link to **BH**, the compilation fails on Linux (I tested on Linux with the help of a Github action).

So, is there a way to link or not to **BH** according to the OS? Or another solution?

Also, if there is such a conditional solution, it would be necessary in addition to include or not `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` in the C++ code according to the OS.

---

## EDIT

I found a possible way: I put **BH** in the **Suggests** field of the **DESCRIPTION** file, not in the **LinkingTo** field, and I use the following **Makevars** file (`BH_PATH` is the relevant variable, the rest was already there):

```
CXX_STD = CXX14
PKG_LIBS = -lmpfr -lgmp -lgmpxx
BH_PATH=`echo 'cat(system.file("include", package="BH", mustWork=TRUE))' | "${R_HOME}/bin/R" --vanilla --no-echo`
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -DCGAL_HEADER_ONLY=1 -I$(BH_PATH)
```

This has worked on Ubuntu (tested via Github action). Now it remains to check whether this is portable. I gonna check on **Rhub** and ask to CRAN.

Comment: What are the significant warnings?

Comment: @JRR  I pasted one of these warnings in this question: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/70632327/1100107>

Comment: Are you sure it is not acceptable? I'm using BH, I have some compilation warnings because of deprecated stuff from boost yet my packages are ok on CRAN. These warnings are not really from my packages.

Comment: @JRR No, not sure. But in general they don't accept warnings. See my edited post, I found a possible solution.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think your solution is more prone to rejection than your original problem.  Does R CMD check complains about your BH issue?

Comment: Two things.  First, isn't this a very standard situation of determining resource at build time and adjusting?  See for example RcppArmadillo checking for OpenMP.   Second, you do not use `[[Rcpp::depends(...)]]` in a package, it is for `sourceCpp()` only.  So back to configure logic, testing at compile time and adjusting your `-I....` flags as needed.  Also, I'd discuss this on `r-package-devel` and not here if it were my package.

Comment: @JRR The warning are always from BH (and/or Eigen) and CRAN Policy forces me to take `#pragma` statements out ... making it 'louder' than it would be otherwise.  That's how they roll ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you. I always included **[[Rcpp::depends(...)]]** in my packages, you teach me something once again.

Comment: @JRR This is precisely a R CMD check complain.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It does no harm and permits you to source the file individually so marginal net benefits. _But it does not affect header-inclusion in a package build **at all** so it is also somewhat misleading._